# TCL regexp for detecting non-whitespace

Tags: regex, tcl

I am applying tcl regex to these 2 data, I wanted to extract the 2nd column data:

```
1: Common point:  rt123_345_no/qwe_rty/sdf34x56/CFR
2: Common point: NA
```

This regex works for 1st data, but won't work for 2nd data:

```
regexp -inline -expanded -- {Common\spoint:\s+?(\S+)\s+} $line
```

I don't understand why the regex won't work. Please advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues:

- There is no whitespace after `NA`, thus, the last `\s+` will fail the match here by all means
- The `\s+?` lazy pattern sets the greediness for the branch, and the `\S+` will behave as `\S+?`, capturing just one `N` from `NA` since `+?` lazy quantifier makes the regex engine match as few chars matching the quantified pattern as possible.

Use

```
Common\spoint:\s+(\S+)
```

Comment: I'd put a `\y` on the end of that RE to force the match to stop on a word boundary (http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm#M72)

Comment: @DonalFellows Yes, possible. Also, if there must be a whitespace or end of string, the `\s+` may be replaced with `(?:\s+|\Z)`, or even a lookahead like `(?!\S)`. [That all seems to work](https://ideone.com/JUdATM) for the current scenario.